Calculating AUC for very large data in R
I would like to repeatedly calculate Area Under Curve type values (both AUROC and AUPRC) as well as average precision for a dataset that's larger then 2^32 rows. I have the dataset sliced up in multiple chunks from previous calculations, and now normally I would just rbind them and then calculate AUC (I'm using evalmod). That works well for a smaller 'data.table', but I repeatedly have dataset that can't be rowbound because of R's (frankly stupid) limit of 2^32 rows. Can somebody point me to a solution how I can either

'rbind' the data into a different class for large dataset to then calculate AUC on, or
how I can calculate these values in parts for each slice, so that I can calculate the overall AUC from that later.

Thank you in advance :)
PS: RAM is not the problem, since the data can be held in memory in slices
